# Error: object not found after a function in 'R'

Tags: r

I have a project to do which is why the data is split into 3. I need to use the data from D1 but it keeps saying that D1 isn't found even though it's defined in the function. Help please :) :

```
    diabetes<-read.table("diabetes_data.txt",T)
    attach(diabetes)
    dimnames(diabetes)

#splitting the data
    group3.split=function(diabetes,group.num)
{

  set.seed(28)
  index.1=1:442
  d1=sort(sample(index.1,size=180,replace=FALSE))
  index.2=index.1[-d1]
  d2=sort(sample(index.2,size=180,replace=FALSE))
  d3=sort(c(d1,d2))
  test.d=index.1[-c(d3)]
  D1=diabetes[d1,]
  D2=diabetes[d2,]
  D3=diabetes[d3,]
  D.test=diabetes[test.d,]
  list(D1=D1, D2=D2, D3=D3, D.test=D.test)
}

#Renaming
Y=D1$Y
X1=D1$AGE
X2=D1$SEX
X3=D1$BMI
X4=D1$BP
X5=D1$S1
X6=D1$S2
X7=D1$S4
X8=D1$S4
X9=D1$S5
X10=D1$S6
```

Comment: This is a scoping problem.  You need to run `group3.split`, save the results in a variable, and extract `D1` from that list.  A reproducible example would help a lot ...

Comment: You have to save the result of the function in an object : `res <- group3.split(diabetes,group.num)`. Be careful : argument `group.num` is not used. Then $Y = res$D1$Y$...

Comment: This is just another way of saying what the other two comments have said: you define the function `group3.split(...)`, *but you never call it*. So `D1` is *not* defined.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks so much Ben and Vincent!